Name for unnormalised probability density functions
Is there a name for the "unnormalised" probability density function? I've tried searching for "density function" but that points back to probability density functions.
For example, the normal distribution has the probability density function
$$
f(x;\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) = \frac{1}{N}g(x;\mu,\sigma^2)
$$
where $N$ is a normalisation constant (also called the partition function in statistical physics).
Is there a name for $g(x)$?

I've only ever seen those refered to explicitly as "unnormalized density" (e.g. in the Stan probabilistic programming language manual.
Note also that the unnormalized density is not uniquely defined - depending on which (if any) arguments to the density are assumed to be constant and how one arranges subexpressions in the density, one may obtain different "constant" terms.

Good point, I hadn't considered that $g$ is not unique. I suppose I should start with a definition for $g$ and define $f$ afterwards.
